# Is there a CLI Command to get a list of ALL policies attached to a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I see CLI commands to list managed policies, inline policies but don't see any single command to list all policies for a user. Do I need to use multiple commands to get all the policies? Also Is there any command to list all the managed policies of a user NOT direct attached--eg attached from a Group?

Comment: All of the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) commands related to IAM can be found at: [iam — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/index.html). Which commands have you tried and which ones are giving you difficulty? Feel free to edit your Question to add more detail.

Comment: have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need separate command for inline and attached policies.
For group policy, you can use `list-group-policies` and for policies attached with role, you can use `list-role-policies`

Comment: how to download inline policies?